# Cannot boot into Ubuntu after resetting NVRAM on iMac

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have an iMac and the sole operating system on it is Ubuntu 14.04

I was trying to solve an issue with the DVD drive and so I reset the NVRAM by holding command+option+p+r while the machine was booting. It then rebooted after the NVRAM was reset.

But now it will not boot into Ubuntu. It simply tries to boot from an empty NTFS partition that I have on the hdd.

It will also will no longer show me the refind boot menu.

If I hold down the option key while booting in order to get into the boot manager, then it simply shows me the empty NTFS partition but does not show me the Ubuntu partition.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Booted the computer from an Ubuntu live usb. Installed and ran Boot-Repair.