# Resolution stuck at 1280x1024 on 2006 iMac

Tags: nvidia, mac, display-resolution

When I first booted into Ubuntu the resolution was correctly set at the native 1920x1200 (iMac 24" Late 2006, GeForce 7600 GT). Now, however, the resolution is stuck at 1280x1024 and nothing higher than that appears in preferences. What I have tried:

- install the Nvidia driver.
- apt-get upgrade
- Set the resolution in Terminal. ("Size 1920x1200 not found in available modes")

Answer (score 0):

Resetting PRAM or NVRAM is a suggested solution, e.g. read https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-mac-pram-or-nvram-2260839.

However, people reported Ubuntu **failing to boot** afterwards and the need to:

- boot imac from the Ubuntu live usb
- install boot-repair
- run boot-repair

See e.g. [Cannot boot into Ubuntu after resetting NVRAM on iMac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655260/cannot-boot-into-ubuntu-after-resetting-nvram-on-imac). So not for the faint hearted and I hope someone provides a better answer and you can ignore mine :).

Comment: I have tried a PRAM reset. No change.

I'm thinking I may need to reinstall the OS to fix this.